# Neo4j - multiple tasks with OPTIONAL MATCH

Tags: cypher, neo4j

I am new to Ne04j, I have to write one cypher query for the following situation
[image]

### **Possiblity 1 :**

- Delete the **NEXT** relationship of the *user* with the *data1*.
- Create the **NEXT** relationship from *user* to *data2*.
- Create the **NEXT** relationship from *data2* to *data1*.

### **Possiblity 2 :**

- Create the **NEXT** relationship from *user* to *data2*.

Problem is with the **Possiblity 1,**  I could not **delete** the relationship and `create` the relationship at the same time.

I have tried the following query,but it fails

```
match (a:user{id:12345}) 
optional match (a)-[r:NEXT]->(b:data) 
delete r 
create unique (a)-[:NEXT]->(c:data{id:1})-[:NEXT]->(b) 
with a 
create unique (a)-[:NEXT]->(c:data{id:2})
```

Please help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I ,found the solution.I am not sure whether this query is perfect, but this working and it tooks only a few milli seconds to execute.

I am posting this answer to help other people having same doubt

```
MATCH (a:user{id:12345})
MERGE (a)-[r:NEXT]->(b:data)
ON CREATE SET b.id=1
with a,r,b
match (a)-[r]->(b)
where b.id<>1
CREATE (a)-[k:NEXT]->(c:data{id:1})-[m:NEXT]->(b)
delete r
```

Hope this helps, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use below cypher query.

```
MATCH (a:user {id: "12345"}) 
WITH a  
MERGE (a)-[:NEXT]->(c:data {id: "2"}) 
WITH a,c
MATCH (a)-[r:NEXT]->(b:data) 
WHERE b<>c 
WITH a, collect(r) AS rels, collect(b) AS bs, c  
FOREACH (t IN range(0,length(rels)-1)| 
FOREACH (t1 IN [bs[t]]| 
FOREACH (t2 IN [rels[t]]|
MERGE c-[:NEXT]->t1 
DELETE t2))) 
RETURN a,c
```

The above query will create a new relation with `node a` and data `node c` with `id: "2"` and if any other nodes of data type previously connected will be appended after new `node c`

Comment: This works only for the possibility 2 as mentioned above in the question.. for the possiblity 2 its returning "query not prepared properly"

Comment: I guess no,its not working for me, Cypher error Query not prepared correctly!  and why using foreach ,I have only one unique NEXT relationship

Comment: Cypher error Query not prepared correctly! , this is the error

Comment: see same thing i tried here in neo4j live try :
http://www.neo4j.org/learn/try

And the query 

MATCH (a:Crew { name: "Morpheus" }) 
WITH a  MERGE (a)-[:NEXT]->(c:data { id: "4" }) 
WITH a,c 
MATCH (a)-[r:NEXT]->(b:data) 
WHERE b<>c 
WITH a, collect(r) AS rels, collect(b) AS bs, c  FOREACH (t IN range(0,length(rels)-1)| FOREACH (t1 IN [bs[t]]| FOREACH (t2 IN [rels[t]]| MERGE c-[:NEXT]->t1 
                                                                                                                         DELETE t2))) 
RETURN a,c

Comment: keep changing the c data node id and will work as your requirement.. the query works fine here..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47874/discussion-between-sumeet-sharma-and-sarathsprakash)

Comment: I have changed the id already , but it displays like Query not prepared correctly!

Comment: did you try the query on the link i gave??

Comment: yes I checked , its working online. but not on my system

Comment: can you any how create a sample dump of your dataset and share so that i can look into it??

Comment: There is not much with the dataset, I just created a usernode and am applying this  , just look at the diagram above. If the code is successful then only I prefer doing the rest.